# Using IN or a text search

Tags: sql, mysql, optimization

I want to search a table to find all rows where one particular field is one of two values. I know exactly what the values would be, but I'm wondering which is the most efficient way to search for them:

for the sake of example, the two values are "xpoints" and "ypoints". I know for certain that there will be no other values in that field which has "points" at the end, so the two queries I'm considering are:

```
WHERE `myField` IN ('xpoints', 'ypoints')
--- or...
WHERE `myField` LIKE '_points'
```

which would give the best results in this case?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As always with SQL queries, run it through the profiler to find out.  However, my gut instinct would have to say that the IN search would be quicker.  Espcially in the example you gave, if the field was indexed, it would only have to do 2 lookups.  If you did a like search, it may have to do a scan, because you are looking for records that end with a certain value. It would also be more accurate as LIKE '_points' could also return 'gpoints', or any other similar string.

Comment: of course, it will depend on the table's actual size...If it is small then the optimiser will simply choose a table scan.

Answer (score 1):

Unless all of the data items in the column in question start with 'x' or 'y', I believe IN will always give you a better query.  If it is indexed, as @Kibbee points out, you will only have to perform 2 lookups to get both.  Alternatively, if it is not indexed, a table scan using IN will only have to check the first letter most of the time whereas with LIKE it will have to check two characters every time (assuming all items are at least 2 characters) -- since the first character is allowed to be anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try it and see.  Create a large amount of test data,  Also, try it with and without an index on myfield.  While you are at it,  see if there's a noticeable difference between
LIKE '*points' and LIKE 'xpoint*'.

It depends on what the optimizer does with each query.

For small amounts of data, the difference will be negligible.  Do whichever one makes more sense.  For large amounts of data the amount of disk I/O matters much more than the amount of CPU time.

I'm betting that IN will get you better results than LIKE, if there is an index on myfield. I'm also betting that 'xpoint_' runs faster than '_points'.  But there's nothing like trying it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL can't use an index when using string comparisons such as LIKE '%foo' or '_foo', but can use an index for comparisons like 'foo%' and 'foo_'.

So in your case, IN will be much faster assuming that the field is indexed.

If you're working with a limited set of possible values, it's worth specifying the field as an ENUM - MySQL will then store it internally as an integer and make this sort of lookup much faster, and save disk space.

Answer (score 0):

It will be faster to do the IN-version than the LIKE-version. Especially when your wildcard isn't at the end of the comparison, but even under ideal conditions IN would still be ideal up until your query nears the size of your max-query insert.